# Setting AVPlayerViewController.player to nil breaks closed captions

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

Per Apple's documentation, when you want to play the audio content of a video in the background you must disconnect the `AVPlayer` from its `AVPlayerViewController` or `AVPlayerLayer` when the application is moved to the background in order to prevent the audio from automatically pausing:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/playing_audio_from_a_video_asset_in_the_background

I noticed that in iOS 13, doing this causes closed captions to break. I created a new project (single view app) to create a minimum reproduction case for this issue. My storyboard consists of a single view with a single button, and the button is connected to my view controller as an action ("playPressed"). Here is the code of my `ViewController.m`:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  AVPlayerViewControllerBug
//
//  Created by Steven Barnett on 9/27/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 BlueFrame Tech. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    @private
    AVPlayerViewController *controller;
    AVPlayer *player;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vcloud.blueframetech.com/file/hls/143758.m3u8"]];
    controller.player = player;

    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:nil];

}

- (IBAction)playPressed:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // Since we're ONLY observing "rate" on the player, assume
    // that's what changed to call this
    AVPlayer *player = (AVPlayer*)object;

    if (player.rate == 0)
    {
        // Unbind the player from the view controller when paused
        controller.player = nil;

        // Since I haven't built custom controls for the player,
        // when it's unbound there's no way to hit the play
        // button. So we'll just start playing after a timer
        // has elapsed
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 repeats:NO block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
            [player play];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        // Re-bind the player when playing
        controller.player = player;
    }
}

@end
```

If you copy this code to your own app, or just try it for yourself, you'll see that when `controller.player = nil` is called, it causes captions to cease working on the `AVPlayer`. The only way I've found to fix it is to delete the `AVPlayer` object and create a whole new `AVPlayer` to replace it.

Is there something I'm missing, some method call I'm not aware of, or something I'm misunderstanding? Or is this just an iOS 13 bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a less-than-elegant solution to this problem that works!

When you call `controller.player = nil;` you must also ***completely destroy the AVPlayerViewController***: `[controller.view removeFromSuperview]; controller = nil;`

Then when you want to set the player once more, you create a new AVPlayerViewController. This will cause a blip in the audio and video (about 0.1 seconds), but the captions will work!